# Woocommerce redirect loop error when deleting product with Aurum theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have used woocommerce and Aurum theme for my cart page.

When i remove any product from the cart **it redirects to a blank page** with the following URL:

URL here..*/cart/?removed_item=1* (which it should).

If I refresh the page (after a while) I get an Internal Server Error.

Then, after a min., if I refresh again, I get the cart page which is empty.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
A.